# Why does a rainbow effect appear when looking through two tinted glasses?

Tags: visible-light

Why does wearing my sunglasses while looking out my tinted driverside window cause a rainbow effect on reflective surfaces?  One without the other, and everything looks normal.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, your sunglasses are polarized, and your side window is tempered glass.   Reflection of light from a non-metal surface, at a glancing angle, causes some linear light polarization.  Tempered glass (because of internal strains) can rotate the polarization of light in a color-dependent way, and your sunglasses transmit only light of one polarization, which causes dimming or tinting of the things you see.

For a good time, put a bottle of corn syrup between two polarizing films,
and enjoy the colors (the molecules of the sugars in corn syrup are stronger color-dependent rotators of light than strains in glass).

The safety glass of a windshield isn't tempered, but a car's rear window might also show the effect.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an effect due to polarization. Try rotating your sunglasses 90 Degrees and see if the effect changes, if it does then this might suggest that there is a phase shift that each wavelength acquire upon reflection.

Comment: Without explaining what polarization is and how it leads to the effect, this is not really a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

The rainbow effect is due to the window tint film. It is polyester (PET), which is birefringent. Birefringent film causes a colored band pattern if the film is sandwiched between two polarizers. The reflective surface and your sunglasses are the two polarizers. The polarized wave interferes with itself as in [this diagram](http://www.olympusmicro.com/primer/images/birefringence/opticalbirefringence.jpg). The interference is wavelength dependent, resulting in colored bands.